# Why do we need axiom of choice to prove that there does not a exist definition of $P(A)$, defined for all subsets $A \subset [0, 1]$

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I'm reading "A First Look At Rigorous Probability" by Jeffrey S. Rosenthal. On chapter one there is a proof which I can't fully understand.

> Suppose, to the contrary, that $P(A)$ could be so defined for each
>   subset $A \subseteq [0. 1]$. We will derive a contradiction to this.
>   Define an equivalence relation on [0. 1] by: $x~y$ if and only if the
>   difference $y  - x$ is rational. This relation partitions the interval
>   $[0. 1]$ into a disjoint union of equivalence classes. Let $H$ be a
>   subset of $[0, 1]$ consisting of precisely one element from each
>   equivalence class (such $H$ must exist by the Axiom of Choice). ....

My question is this: If we assume the Power Set Axiom, why do we need Axiom of Choice here. If the power set of $A$ exists, then its elements also exist. I mean, how can a set contain non-existent objects? And $H$ is clearly in the power set of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we don't need the Axiom of Choice in order to be able to talk about $\mathcal{P}\bigl([0,1]\bigr)$. But we *do* need it when, after defining an equivalence relation on $[0,1]$, you want to work with a set with one and only one element of each equivalence class. This is a straightforward application of the Axiom of Choice: we have a family of sets (the equivalence classes) and we want to have a set with one and only one element from each set of that family.

Comment: To the proposer: Let $E$ be the set of equivalence classes. AC is needed for the existence of a function $f:E\to \Bbb R$ such that $\forall e\in E\,(f(e)\in e).$

Answer (score 1):

$P(A)$ is **not** the power set operator. It is the probability operator, I am guessing they mean the standard uniform one.

Indeed, Solovay proved that it is consistent that the probability measures all sets. So the axiom of choice is really needed.

---

The point is that just like $\sqrt2$ or $\pi$ are not members of *every* field, the power set operation is not fully decided by the existence of a power set. In particular, in different set theoretic universes there will be power sets that disagree with each other.

What choice allows you, is to prove that there are non-measurable sets. The fact that there are mathematical universes where all sets are measurable means that without choice it is indeed impossible to prove such sets exists: they don't exist in *some* models of $\sf ZF$.

Comment: Yes, it is not the power set operator. But in general, why do we need axiom of choice to construct (maybe "construct" is not the right word) $H$, if it is already in the power set of $A$?

Comment: Why is it necessarily "in the power set"?

Comment: @AshotJanibekyan Sure, you can set up the criterion "$H$ contains one element from each equivalence class", so one can easily _check_ whether a given set is like that or not without the axiom of choice. But without choice (or something similar) we can't guarantee that such a set _exists_.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Because the power set is the set of all subsets :/ I think you mean we need Axiom of Choice to say that $H$ is a "subset" of $A$?

Comment: @Ashot: I have edited my answer to help and clarify.